# Cannot see Apache2 in Browser Ubuntu 20.04lts

Tags: networking, server, permissions, apache2

I have installed Apache 2 in Ubuntu 20.04lts and have confirmed it is running and I have configured UFW to allow Apache Full and have confirmed they are running.

However when I put the Local IP address, localhost in my browser I get the Forbidden Access warning;
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

How can I fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The standard path inclusions are in five files wrote
/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/web-data.dpkg-dist
/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/web-data
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

all entries with

`#/var/www/html`

should be uncomment to

`/var/www/html`

also should there in /var/www/html a file to be
which is telling you all is right if you enter the address http://localhost
please use the complete address than any browsers are toggling alone to https://
if you use only localhost

Comment: apache2 is super all secure and saved all files in parent-folders above the set folder from access of guests

Comment: I am removing all server programs and will try to find a way to install Magento 2.4.2 on Ubuntu 20.04LTS.

Comment: Thank you but this is all greek to me. I am purging all the server programs from my Ubunto 20.04lts system and will try to find a beginner friendly install path for a localhost - not internet attached Magento 2.4.2 test bed.

Comment: This suggestion did not work. Thank you

Comment: We should close the thread